# Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined while Firebase Deployment

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to deploy my **Angular 2** application on **Firebase**.
All is well and good even in prod mode in Local.

Once deployed, I get the content on the screen without styles and all the data of my **Modal** strewed across the screen.

Console shows the error as:
**Uncaught TypeError**: Cannot read property '**ngOriginalError**' of undefined

I have been smashing my head for quite a while now

I am pretty sure , this has to do with Jquery as I am using Injection Token.

Any kind of assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out however.

I was using bootstrap and jquery directly from node modules.

Changed my index.html to get those values directly from CDN.

Hope this helps somebody.